# Reading pixel numbers of georeferenced raster in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, georeferencing

In the following map, I've georeferenced the `pauliRGB.bmp` of an ALOS-PALSAR image in order to be able to exactly recognize the number of pixels which San francisco is surrounded by. I mean, I want be able to read the line and column number of the four corners of the red rectangle. Is there any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use the methods described in Esri's technical article on [How To: Locate the column and row of a point within a raster](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010981)

Basically it is explaining that Locating the exact pixel location (column and row) of a point within a raster can be done one of two ways: the first uses the Field Calculator in the attribute table of the point feature class **created at required locations**, and the second utilizes Spatial Analyst.